# New Rancher installation: Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes

After having problems with connectivity in my old (working completely fine until it didn't) Rancher installation in my homelab, I decided to reinstall my single-node Rancher installation on k3s (running on Ubuntu server) from scratch, hoping that this would be the easiest way, but it still does not work.

The admin UI is not accessible, any requests to the configured domain are timing out (the same problem I had before). So here are all steps I used in order to set it up:

- uninstall k3s: `/usr/local/bin/k3s-uninstall.sh`
- reinstall supported k3s version: `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_VERSION=v1.25.11+k3s1 sh -s - server --cluster-init`
- add helm chart: `helm repo add rancher-latest https://releases.rancher.com/server-charts/latest`
- copy k3s config in order to be able to run `kubectl` commands instead of `sudo k3s kubectl`: `sudo cp /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml ~/.kube/config && sudo chown aalex:aalex ~/.kube/config`
- create cattle-system namespace: `kubectl create namespace cattle-system`
- install cert-manager:

`kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.11.0/cert-manager.crds.yaml`

`helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io`

`helm repo update`

`helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager   --namespace cert-manager   --create-namespace   --version v1.11.0`

- install rancher: `helm install rancher rancher-latest/rancher --namespace cattle-system --set hostname=rancher.mydomain.tld --set replicas=1 --set bootstrapPassword=password`

This then shows that within a couple of minutes, the Rancher backend should be accessible. I have configured the DNS entry to point to my public IP address and forwarded port 80, 443 and 32400 to point to the ubuntu server, so on the ingress side everything should be working. I suspect the problems to be internal because when I run

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                                       READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
cattle-system   helm-operation-2786k                       1/2     Error       0          30m
cattle-system   helm-operation-2bvsk                       1/2     Error       0          20m
cattle-system   helm-operation-2kbjh                       1/2     Error       0          34m
cattle-system   helm-operation-2szb7                       1/2     Error       0          17m
cattle-system   helm-operation-5bksl                       1/2     Error       0          39m
cattle-system   helm-operation-5rx7n                       1/2     Error       0          21m
cattle-system   helm-operation-75cwd                       2/2     Running     0          4m3s
cattle-system   helm-operation-7t5g8                       2/2     Running     0          8m16s
cattle-system   helm-operation-8dkxf                       1/2     Error       0          24m
cattle-system   helm-operation-9jpts                       2/2     Running     0          9m19s
cattle-system   helm-operation-dvg87                       1/2     Error       0          11m
cattle-system   helm-operation-gbv8w                       1/2     Error       0          13m
cattle-system   helm-operation-hql8h                       1/2     Error       0          10m
cattle-system   helm-operation-k4pcm                       1/2     Error       0          28m
cattle-system   helm-operation-kh7kf                       1/2     Error       0          31m
cattle-system   helm-operation-ldm9n                       1/2     Error       0          15m
cattle-system   helm-operation-lf7zt                       1/2     Error       0          26m
cattle-system   helm-operation-p9kmb                       1/2     Error       0          18m
cattle-system   helm-operation-ppmhg                       1/2     Error       0          38m
cattle-system   helm-operation-pz6rd                       1/2     Error       0          14m
cattle-system   helm-operation-q7f42                       1/2     Error       0          19m
cattle-system   helm-operation-qhzzn                       1/2     Error       0          35m
cattle-system   helm-operation-qkffm                       2/2     Running     0          5m6s
cattle-system   helm-operation-qlh5q                       2/2     Running     0          116s
cattle-system   helm-operation-r5vgm                       2/2     Running     0          6m10s
cattle-system   helm-operation-r8w2t                       2/2     Running     0          54s
cattle-system   helm-operation-rwrcn                       1/2     Error       0          27m
cattle-system   helm-operation-s4xgh                       1/2     Error       0          12m
cattle-system   helm-operation-sl8s2                       1/2     Error       0          25m
cattle-system   helm-operation-sptzf                       1/2     Error       0          36m
cattle-system   helm-operation-vcxsq                       1/2     Error       0          16m
cattle-system   helm-operation-vwz4t                       2/2     Running     0          3m
cattle-system   helm-operation-x2w9x                       1/2     Error       0          32m
cattle-system   helm-operation-x69qf                       1/2     Error       0          33m
cattle-system   helm-operation-x95fc                       1/2     Error       0          22m
cattle-system   helm-operation-z8z67                       1/2     Error       0          29m
cattle-system   helm-operation-zk5h9                       2/2     Running     0          7m13s
cattle-system   helm-operation-zk8j7                       1/2     Error       0          37m
cattle-system   rancher-669557c8fd-cmrb2                   1/1     Running     0          43m
cert-manager    cert-manager-59bf757d77-84gkv              1/1     Running     0          46m
cert-manager    cert-manager-cainjector-547c9b8f95-lz9cd   1/1     Running     0          46m
cert-manager    cert-manager-webhook-6787f645b9-b6xjf      1/1     Running     0          46m
kube-system     coredns-8b9777675-qplrr                    1/1     Running     0          47m
kube-system     helm-install-traefik-8m7ck                 0/1     Completed   1          47m
kube-system     helm-install-traefik-crd-7q4f8             0/1     Completed   0          47m
kube-system     local-path-provisioner-69dff9496c-sqx5q    1/1     Running     0          47m
kube-system     metrics-server-854c559bd-2m7rd             1/1     Running     0          47m
kube-system     svclb-traefik-2bcb49c9-vmk8h               2/2     Running     0          46m
kube-system     traefik-66fd46ccd-54v59                    1/1     Running     0          46m
```

As you can see, the helm-operations are erroring out. When taking a look at the logs, they do not say much:

```
aalex@macmini-ubuntu:~$ kubectl -n cattle-system logs helm-operation-2786k
Defaulted container "helm" out of: helm, proxy
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Waiting for Kubernetes API to be available
Timeout waiting for kubernetes
```

Can someone please help me? What can be the reason that the Kubernetes API is not available for some of these pods? Which commands should I run next in order to troubleshoot this problem?

I found a bunch of threads like [this github issue](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/41296) but most of them have no answers how it could be fixed and I'm not experienced enough in Kubernetes to be able to

> check that your cluster's k8s API is communicating properly.

on my own.

Comment: I have this same issue on K8s v1.28.2 - any hope?